# Proper Facebook PHP SDK login route

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to setup a basic login w/Facebook button.

This is basically what I'm copying:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login

The only differences are I'm trying to setup everything in one file (so I can keep all the social sign-on code in one spot), and I'm hoping to create the link and redirect the user all in one.

When I hit the page generated by the handler, I get a "Sorry this page isn't available" message.

The twitter flow is basically the same (it's complete and functioning without issues). I do save the oauth tokens to a database, which I haven't gotten around to doing yet with the Facebook part yet. It'll save the the save table, I just save the oauth provider or something along with the tokens.

Here's the gist:

```
switch(strtolower($_REQUEST['method'])) {    
case 'twitter':
    /*ommited, but it's basically the same flow*/
    break;

case 'facebook':
    // if we don't have a step, we don't know what to do
    if (!isset($_REQUEST['step'])) {
        die('Fail: invalid step: (none)');
    }

    // we'll be using the Facebook PHP SDK
    require(FACEBOOK_SDK_PATH);

    switch(strtolower($_REQUEST['step'])) {
        case 1:
            // instantiates a new SDK App object
            $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
                'app_id' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
                'app_secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
                'default_graph_version' => '2.0'
            ]);

            // gets helper
            $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

            // optional permissions parameter
            // we want the users email address
            $permissions = ['email'];

            // generates the url for the user to authorize access
            $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/social-login.php?method=facebook&step=2', $permissions);

            // redirect user
            header('Location: ' . $loginUrl);

            break;

        case 2:
            // this should include an access token so we can get information about the user and consider them authenticated
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($_SESSION);
            var_dump($_REQUEST);
            echo '</pre>';
            die();

            break;

        default:
            die('Fail: invalid step: ' . $_REQUEST['step']);
    }
    break;

default:
    die('Fail: invalid method . ' . $_REQUEST['method']);
}
```

I've poured over the documentation above and just can't figure out what's missing. Could it be a setting on the app side? An issue with the localhost callback?

I matched the default graph version to whatever the app gets set as (2.0). I'm not sure if I can change that or not, but I see a lot of code using 2.2 and 2.5 and I can't figure out if that could be part of my issues either. I would assume not, but figured I'd put a note here.

Comment: _“I get a "Sorry this page isn't available" message”_ – where from? Is it a message you app outputs explicitly? Or are you just referring to the browser’s default error page? Check what’s going on in the browser’s dev tools network panel – do you see a 500 or other server-side error there? Go check the server’s log files.

Comment: @CBroe this is the message I get when I redirect to the URL generated by the SDK. http://i.imgur.com/XWhpDpb.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'app_secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    'default_graph_version' => '2.0'
]);
```

You specified the API version wrong, and therefor the SDK has created the wrong login dialog URL.

You need to include the `v`:

```
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.0'
```